# how to set connection string and host a asp.net web application (having windows authentication) in local for SQL Server for multiple users?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis

I am trying to host an ASP.NET web application in my local, which is connected to various other computers via LAN. I have a single DB in SQL server, but I am unable to set the connection string for multiple users. I use windows authentication for my web application. Please help to set the connection string for multiple users.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "connection string for multiple users" - you can have your connection use "Integrated Security" and configure IIS (Application Pool) to pass the user context. However I believe you are designing a system that will lead to lots of problems further down the road.

Comment: Thank you. But can you please tell me the problems I am gonna face

Comment: I would expect your first problem will be identifying database record owners. ASP.NET offers out-of-the-box authentication and authorization providers that use one database connection that can be tied to the Application Pool User as mentioned in @DiskJunky's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one a few ways;

- You create a SQL account and put the login details in the connection string
- You create a SQL account and an ODBC connection and connect via the ODBC connection (has the virtue of not putting the password in the connection string)
- You create a Windows account and use those credentials for the application's IIS App Pool when the site is deployed.

Any of those approaches will allow you to have your Windows auth turned on but still allow the application to use only one identity to connect to the database.